# how to get kernel header file?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

i'm trying to make new system calls in kernel 2.6.21

and one of the new system calls use 'sys_write' function,

but to use this function, i realized that i must install kernel header file according to 2.6.21 version.

but i can't find kernel header file(2.6.21)

i tried `apt-get install linux-headers-'uname -r'` , `apt-cache search linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

but i can't find anything..

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/syscalls.h>
#include <linux/fcntl.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h>

int main(){
    int fd;
    int old_fs;
    old_fs = get_fs();
    set_fs(KERNEL_DS);
    fd = sys_open("config.txt", O_RDONLY, 0);
    if(fd >= 0)
        sys_close(fd);
    set_fs(old_fs);
    return 0;
}



 vv.c:2:24: error: linux/init.h: No such file or directory  
 vv.c:3:26: error: linux/module.h: No such file or directory  
 vv.c:4:28: error: linux/syscalls.h: No such file or directory  
 In file included from /usr/include/asm/fcntl.h:1,  
                 from /usr/include/linux/fcntl.h:4,  
                 from vv.c:5:  
 /usr/include/asm-generic/fcntl.h:120: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘off_t’  
 /usr/include/asm-generic/fcntl.h:143: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘loff_t’  
  vv.c:6:25: error: asm/uaccess.h: No such file or directory  
 vv.c: In function ‘main’:  
 vv.c:12: error: ‘KERNEL_DS’ undeclared (first use in this function)  
 vv.c:12: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once  
 vv.c:12: error: for each function it appears in.)
```

additionally, above header files is what i want to.

how can i get the kernel header file?

please help me..

Comment: Why do you want to add a new system call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did installing the headers complete? If so then they should be installed in `/usr/include` and the include directives you gave should just work.

Edit:

First run:

`sudo apt-get update`

To make sure you have the latest packages, then:

`sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

This is the one package that should contain all the kernel header files in Ubuntu.

Comment: no i think Not all the header file installed. because i can't find these header files in my ubuntu. that's why i am trying to find how to get them.

Comment: @onteria sorry, what mean "See the inline response"?

Comment: @onteria first was done successfully, and second, there are not linux-headers-2.6.21